# 'dict' object has no attribute 'data' Decission Tree

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a Decission Tree and this appear to me

'dict' object has no attribute 'data'

```
from google.colab import files 
uploaded = files.upload()

a = uploaded
X = pd.DataFrame(a.data[: , :], columns = a.feature_names[:]) # El dataframe es una matriz en pandas
y = pd.DataFrame(a.target, columns = [''])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-640b9d63e9b5> in <module>()
      1 a = uploaded
----> 2 X = pd.DataFrame(a.data[: , :], columns = a.feature_names[:]) # El dataframe es una matriz en pandas
      3 y = pd.DataFrame(a.target, columns = [''])

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: It looks like your variable a is of type `dict`. You can try to creade a pandas Dataframe by passing a dict directly to it like `pd.DataFrame(a)`. Then print the output and take a look on the date.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the value of a is probably just the filename of the file and not the content.
You should use the according method of pandas based on the extension of uploaded for example if it was a .csv

`df = pd.read_csv(uploaded)`